# ViewPager внутри другого ViewPager. Проблема перелистывания страниц

Tags: android-viewpager, android, touch-event

Есть ViewPager, внутри которого расположен еще один ViewPager.  
Внутренний пейджер на касания реагировать не должен, в нем страницы переключаются по таймеру. А вот внешний - должен.  
Как сделать так, что бы на свайп по внутреннему пейджеру реагировал только внешний?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутренние

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean enabled;

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.enabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
} }
```